# How to change X and Y coordinates of window without recreating it

Tags: c, ncurses, xterm

Suppose I created a window by **newwin()** with cordinates X and Y = (0 and 0) but now I have changed my mind and want to change X and Y coords without recreating window using **newwin()** then how to do it ?
My main goal is to recreate **box()** with new X and Y coords after resizing terminal (xterm)

Answer (score 1):

I got it, using **[mvwin()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvwin)**
For example `mvwin(win,newY,newX)`